# gorm fails to populate nested structures with data after joining mysql tables

Tags: go-gorm

Here I am trying to join the three tables Branches_organization, oragnization, and locations  and sent them as API response. However, organizationand location json fails to fetch any data.

**Issue:**

The below API response fails to retrieve organization and location details; always return zero values

```
{
    "Title": "OK",
    "status": 200,
    "records": 1,
    "data": [
        {
            "branch_id": 51,
            "name": "my branch name",
            "address": "Mun",
            "telephone": "+9xxxxx",
            "organization": {
                "org_id": 0,
                "name": ""
            },
            "location": {
                "loc_id": 0,
                "name": ""
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Error on the console

```
2022/08/17 06:11:32 /apiserver/controllers/handlers.go:3475 invalid field found for struct apiserver/entities.Custom_branches_organization's field Organization: define a valid foreign key for relations or implement the Valuer/Scanner interface
[7.930ms] [rows:1] SELECT branches_organization.branch_id,branches_organization.name,branches_organization.address,branches_organization.telephone,organization.org_id,organization.name,location.loc_id,location.name FROM `branches_organization` left join  organization on organization.org_id = branches_organization.org_id left join  location on location.loc_id =  branches_organization.loc_id
```

**Implementation details**

structures used

Struct used for API response

```
type Custom_branches_organization struct {
    Branch_id    uint         `json:"branch_id"`
    Name         string       `json:"name" validate:"required"`
    Address      string       `json:"address" validate:"required"`
    Telephone    string       `json:"telephone" validate:"e164,required"`
    Organization Organization `json:"organization" gorm:"foreignkey:org_id;references:Org_id"`
    Location     Location     `json:"location" gorm:"foreignkey:loc_id;references:Loc_id"`
}
```

child structures
//Organization table in database

```
type Organization struct {
    Org_id    uint   `json:"org_id"`
    Name      string `json:"name" validate:"required"`
    Address   string `json:"address"`
    Telephone string `json:"telephone" validate:"e164,required"`
    Email     string `json:"email" validate:"required,email"`
}
```

//Location table in database

```
type Location struct {
    Loc_id    uint   `json:"loc_id"`
    Name      string `json:"name" validate:"required"`
    Address   string `json:"address" validate:"required"`
    Telephone string `json:"telephone" validate:"e164,required"`
}
```

//Actual Branches table in database

```
type Branches_organization struct {
    Branch_id uint   `json:"branch_id"`
    Name      string `json:"name" validate:"required"`
    Address   string `json:"address" validate:"required"`
    Telephone string `json:"telephone" validate:"e164,required"`
    Org_id    uint   `json:"org_id" validate:"number"`
    Loc_id    uint   `json:"loc_id" validate:"number"`
}
```

**Gorm implementation**

//Retrieve all records from the branches_organization table

```
var branches_organizations []entities.Custom_branches_organization

result := database.Instance.Model(&entities.Branches_organization{}).Preload("Organization").Preload("Location").Select("branches_organization.branch_id,branches_organization.name,branches_organization.address,branches_organization.telephone,organization.org_id,organization.name,location.loc_id,location.name").Joins("left join  organization on organization.org_id = branches_organization.org_id").Joins("left join  location on location.loc_id =  branches_organization.loc_id").Scan(&branches_organizations)

branches_organizationsdata := entities.Customebranches_organizationData{"OK", http.StatusOK, result.RowsAffected, branches_organizations}

json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(branches_organizationsdata)
```

**Database tables**

```
mysql> desc  organization;
+-----------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| org_id    | int      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name      | longtext | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| address   | longtext | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| telephone | longtext | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| email     | longtext | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
5 rows in set (0.12 sec)

mysql> desc  location;
+-----------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| loc_id    | int      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name      | longtext | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| address   | longtext | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| telephone | longtext | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> desc branches_organization;
+-----------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| branch_id | int      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name      | longtext | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| address   | longtext | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| telephone | longtext | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| org_id    | int      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| loc_id    | int      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-----------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I am breaking my head for many days to create an json reply which will have organization and location details as nested structures. Hope you can support me.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use the preloading for populating the nested structs, similar to join in sql query. Please refer this doc.

https://gorm.io/docs/preload.html#nested_preloading

```
 type User struct {
  gorm.Model
  Username string
  Orders Order
}
type Order struct {
  gorm.Model
  UserID uint
  Price float64
}   
db.Preload("Username")
db.Preload("Orders").Find(&users)
```